# '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, widget

I took the red screen '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' exception in NoContentPage I wrote down the full component code and called place into StatefulWidget. What is wrong in this code. I think it is a very common exception in the flutter.

```
class NoContentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (new Container(
      width: 320.0,
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).messageNoContent,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    letterSpacing: 0.3,
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

called

```
body: Container(
            child: videos == null
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : videos.length == 0
                    ? NoContentPage
                    : ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: videos.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                playYoutubeVideo(videos[index][Video.videoUrl]);
                              },
                              child: Column(children: [
                                new YoutubeCard(
                                  video: videos[index],
                                ),
                                new Divider(
                                  height: 0.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ]));
                        }),
          )
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your mistake is that you returned the type instead of the instance of a given type:

```
return Foo;
```

vs

```
return Foo();
```

Comment: In your specific case, this is `NoContentPage` the issue.

Comment: i have been fighting with dart for over 3 hours. Thank you for this

Comment: when will they invent a language where the error message will be "you forgot parentheses"

Answer (score 3):

I have faced a very similar problem with error info '' when having following code:

```
    List<Widget> items = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        .map(
          (f) {
            return Text(f);
          },
        )
        .toList();
    items.last = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[items.last],
    );
```

change this code to following works:

```
    List<Widget> items = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        .map(
          (f) {
            return Text(f);
          },
        )
        .cast<Widget>()
        .toList();
    items.last = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[items.last],
    );
```

I think maybe when doing a map, the result type from map function is changed, so the internal dart implemention of list assert fail. Force the cast type works.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this error is very common when you are moving across screens and using network data to be displayed in your apps, using ternary operator for data and progress indicator then the indicator must be called as a Widget `LinearProgressIndicator()` and not `LinearProgressIndicator`.